# How to configure the pre-warmed instances in Azure Functions Premium?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

We were experiencing timeouts the first time a function from a `Function App` was being called so we move from a normal to premium service plan as in theory you can have always a warmed instance ready to answer a call (based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan)).

The thing is that when trying to configure the functionality we cannot see the setting present in the documentation. This is our portal:

[image]

And this is the portal settings appearing in the documentation:

[image]

The functions are still timing out the first time they are called so we did not see any difference moving from a normal plan to the premium one. Are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you need to modify the Function App settings while we were tweaking the Service Plan.

We have there the warmed instances setting but it is not having the expected result, we are still facing the timeouts we had with the normal Service Plan.

Comment: I want to know what the timeout you are experiencing. Is that it doesn't react immediately when be called or  stops after running for a while. I am not sure what the timeout you mean.

Comment: After 30 minutes of no use the first two calls to the function timeout and next calls work propertly.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia We have the same problem. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: I see the same issue. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't reproduce your problem, I can set the `pre-warmed instances` on my portal. But I have an idea to solve this problem.

Try to use **`powshell`** in **`Azure Cloud Shell`** to configure the `pre-warmed instances` of your function app instead of using portal:

`az resource update -g <resource_group> -n <function_app_name>/config/web --set properties.preWarmedInstanceCount=<desired_prewarmed_count> --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites`

Test whether it can be setted. If can't,  have a look of the error. This may be an error with the portal.

If you have doubts, please let me know.